# Reallocation of nested c++ vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, vector

Let us say that we have a structure including an `std::vector` container:

```
struct A {
    char a;  // decoration
    vector<int> v;

    A() {}
};
```

At some point in our code, we have an `std::vector` storing those `A` structures (that means, two levels of `std::vector`s), and after that, we reserve more memory space for `v` on one of its elements:

```
    /*...*/
    vector<A> vect;
    vect.resize(10, A());
    vector<A>* vect_ptr = &vect;
    vect[0].v.reserve(9999999);
    cout << vect_ptr << " ?= " << &vect << endl;
    /*...*/
```

The question is: after reserving space for one of the 'low-level' vectors `v`, does it exist the risk that the 'high-level' vector `vect` is reallocated, making the pointer `vect_ptr` invalid?

In affirmative case, would be redefining `v` as a reference a solution? (even though it adds an indirection level):

```
struct A {
    char a;
    vector<int>& v;

    A() : v(vector<int>()) {}
};
```

Comment: Do you mean to take the address of vect or to take the address of one of its elements? Either way, vect_ptr won't change as a result of any operation on one of the inner vectors v. As written, where vect_ptr is the address of vect, vect_ptr will never change as a result of any operation on vect either.

Comment: You misunderstand what "reallocation" means. An instance of `vector` itself doesn't magically jump around in memory; the data that it manages might. `vect_ptr` will not become invalid for as long as `vect` is alive.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OK! Now I saw it, and Barry's answer completed your comment ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no such risk.

`vect` owns some memory, into which it writes a bunch of `A`s: So maybe in memory something like this:

```
[--A--][--A--][--A--]...[--A--]
^                       ^
&vect[0]                &vect[9]
```

But each one of those `A`s has some vector that points to some more memory somewhere else. Here's a crude illustration of what `vect[1].v` might point to:

```
         [int][int][int][int][int]...
         ^
         |
[--A--][--A--][--A--]...[--A--]
^                       ^
&vect[0]                &vect[9]
```

(I apologize for the horrible ascii art)

The two containers own their own memory which does not overlap. Resizing one of the "inner" vectors may change what memory it owns, but it has nothing to do with what memory `vect` owns (unless your allocator is seriously broken, which `std::allocator` is not). You can think of `vect`'s memory as being completely off-limits to what anything else will try to allocate. It doesn't matter how much you try to allocate in one of the "inner" vectors. At some point, you will fail to allocate that much memory, but there will never be any risk of reallocating any other object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. I don't think the Standard actually guarantees that. It is implementation defined and should work for the most implementations of std::vector. But that is not a point you can rely on.

Maybe an iterator has aditional debug informations wich are refering the original container - you get into trouble.